# Read environmet variable from cordova hook

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, cordova-hooks

I have an ionic project which hosts the environment variables under **src/environments/** which has classic **environment.ts** *and* **environment.prod.ts** files.

In the root folder, I have my [cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/) under **scripts/afterBuild.js**

In my **config.xml** i call my hook like this:

```
<hook src="/scripts/afterBuild.js" type="after_build" />
```

**QUESTION**

How can I read the production variable from the environment.ts file to my **afterBuild.js** script?

> environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  ...
  production: false
};
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRY**

I can only read the file as text but cannot find a way to parse it.

> afterBuild.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  var envFile = 'src/environments/environment.ts';
  var configFileFull = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, envFile);
  var configData = fs.readFileSync(configFileFull, 'utf8');
  console.log(configData)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. It goes like this:

When I run a cordova commande like for example:

```
cordova build
```

I can run it like this

```
cordova build --prod --something --somethingElse false
```

then, the ctx variable from

```
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  ...
};
```

has the

```
...
opts:{
   ...,
   options: { production: true, something: true, somethingElse: false }
},
...
```

It is not the best solution for me but it could work. Any other solution welcome :)